# How to execute ubuntu command in python code?

Tags: command-line, python

I have to execute this code in python

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-prev "'Disabled'"
```

Tried With:

```
os.system('dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-prev "Disabled" ')
```

Error:

```
error: 0-1:unknown keyword

Usage:
  dconf write KEY VALUE 

Write a new value to a key

Arguments:
  KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
  VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)
```

Please help me on this issue. thanks :-)

Comment: Have you tried with `Disabled` in double and single quotes like `os.system('dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-prev "'Disabled'" ')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Editing dconf/gsettings from python

You really shouldn't use `os.system()` for system calls anymore, it has been deprecated and totally outdated for a long time.

There are different options to edit the `dconf` database.

#### Using subprocess

Say I have a `dconf` path `/com/gexperts/Tilix/keybindings/app-shortcuts`, I can use:

```py
import subprocess

key = "/com/gexperts/Tilix/keybindings/app-shortcuts"

subprocess.Popen([
    "dconf", "write", key, "'enabled'"
])
```

Mind the quoting!

---

In most cases however, you will also be able to use (better)`gsettings`. Use `Gio.Settings` if the value also can be set from `gsettings`.

---

#### Using Gio.Settings

```py
from gi.repository import Gio

key = "com.gexperts.Tilix.Keybindings"

settings = Gio.Settings.new(key)
settings.set_string("app-shortcuts", "enabled")
```

See also https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/Settings.html#Gio.Settings and [https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gio-2.0/Gio.Settings.html](https://people.gnome.org/%7Egcampagna/docs/Gio-2.0/Gio.Settings.html)

#### About gsettings/dconf

Preferences on modern Ubuntu versions are mostly stored in the `dconf` database in binary format. These settings can be edited directly by `dconf` (cli), or `dconf-editor` (gui). Dconf is low level, and directly editing settings via `dconf` extremely fast and light-weight.

In general it is however considered better practice to edit settings in the database via `gsettings` if possible, which is the cli frontend to `dconf`. The reason is that `gsettings` has a consistency check, safer to use.

You might find this an interesting read on `gsettings`: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html

And this one on `dconf`: https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html

#### Notes

- I used another path / key example since I don't run Unity.

Comment: dconf code executed for me but If I execute gsettings code I am getting this error  (process:5879): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.unityshell' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped).  I just want to know, why gsettings not executed and dconf executed ? schema of gsettings and dconf same or different . Any how i got resolved my problem :-)

Comment: @Dinesh what version of Ubuntu do you have? Just installed 16.04 in a VM, the key does not exist there. Not in dconf as well.

Comment: update from 14.04 to 16.04. Both seniors working fine . @Jacob thank you for your suggestions and comments